# Не подключается CSS к HTML при создании сайта на DJANGO

Tags: python, html, css, django

Вопрос заключается в том, что не подключается CSS-файл к HTML при создание сайта на django.
Вот как я писал:
(wrapper.html)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/4chats/styles.css">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar">
          <div class="home">
             <a class="link4home" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/"><p class="home_text">HOME</p></a>
          </div>
       </div>
       {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

(static/4chats/styles.css)

```css
    .navbar {
       background-color: #5394d4;
       width: auto;
       height: 65px;
    }
    .home {
       position: absolute;
       left: 45%;
       margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .home_text {
       font-size: 50px;
       font-family: AR CENA;
       color: #d7e4ee;
    }
    .link4home:hover {
       text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы использовать ваш `css` - в начале `html` кода нужно выполнить `{% load static %}`. Затем прописать `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '4chats/styles.css' %}">`. Вот ссылка на [документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/).